# Property in @ConfigurationProperties prefix

Tags: spring, properties, configuration

Is it possible to use a property in

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "${domain}.user")
```

This doesn't work. I just want to "prefix the prefix" with the value from another property from the same properties file. For example:

```
domain=${domain}
domain1.user.username=john
domain2.user.username=irene
```

The full prefix wanted would be `domain1.user` after filtering using "domain1" as a value for the `domain` property.

Answer (score 0):

According to @ConfigurationProperties javadoc:

```
 * Note that contrary to {@code @Value}, SpEL expressions are not evaluated since property
 * values are externalized.
```