# In a SpringBoot application, how to set @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ...) dynamically?

Tags: spring-boot

I wrote a small application which includes a `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ...)` annotation to load the correct configuration for one of the beans. This has been working fine and I've been manually changing the `prefix` value in my IDE as needed when testing against different environments.

Now I need to clean this up and ensure the application can run in different environments without a recompile. The value needs to be parameterized. How can I set the prefix dynamically at run-time?

Related Questions

This other question references a specific approach which doesn't work, using spEL:

> [Property in @ConfigurationProperties prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357078/property-in-configurationproperties-prefix)

and this one says you can't use it YAML (which I don't care about)

> [How to implement dynamic @ConfigurationProperties Prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557138/how-to-implement-dynamic-configurationproperties-prefix)

I'm looking more generally, for any working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think that what you're asking for kind of contradicts spring/ spring boot practices.

Configuration Properties keys have to be static in spring.

This means, that in all environments the same configuration property key must exist.

What changes is a value of the property depending on the environment

For local development you might want to resolve:

Example:

```
my.db.host = localhost
```

For Production however, you'll want something like:

```
my.db.host = myproduction.db.host.real.address.goes.here
```

From Spring's standpoint you have:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.db") 
class MyDbProperties {
   String host;
   ...
}
```

Now the question is how to alter the properties sets of values for dev/stage/local/production etc.

The spring's answer is "profiles"

In spring boot you can start the application with:

```
--spring.profiles.active=dev
```

In this case, the `application-dev.properties` will load automatically (or yaml of course)

So you should create, say, one file per environment and put specific values there:

**application-local.properties**

```
my.db.host=localhost
```

**application-prod.properties**

```
my.db.host=myproduction.db.host.real.address.goes.here
```

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but appears to be the right answer. I changed my code to use profiles in separate files, instead of prefixes.